# Circle fitting validation

Tags: circles

I tried to find out circle center for noisy data. For computation sake I implemented this algorithm https://dtcenter.org/met/users/docs/write_ups/circle_fit.pdf It works fine but sometimes data is more similar to the line rather than circle. I need some parameter which would show me that data is more likely an arc of circle.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVCWh.jpg)

Comment: I would propose a regularized second degree polynomial level set. It is very easy to fit using normal least squares fitting. And with some tweaking and re-weighting you can make more robust fits also (other than the 2-norm).

Comment: Note that in a certain sense (which can be made rigorous), a line segment *is* an arc of an infinitely large circle.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps read up on [model selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_selection#Criteria). A circle has more parameters than a line (3 vs 2), and indeed a circle can, locally, approximate a line arbitrarily well. You should thus expect that a circle always gives a better fit than a line (i.e. the fitting error is always lower), even if the data really is a noisy line.

In order to choose between models with varying numbers of parameters, you need to [penalize the models with more parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_information_criterion).